# Sublime Text 2: sublime commands from custom plugin are unloaded

Tags: plugins, command, sublimetext2

I have a custom plugin (you can find it here https://github.com/chestozo/st-plugins).

In this plugin I have a `Default.sublime-commands` file with commands that should be added to Command Palette in ST2.

Sometimes I cannot find my custom commands in Command Palette.
It looks like my custom commands are unloaded. Is it possible?

**UPDATE**
What I have found is that:

- when no file is opened in current project - you see one set of commands in Commands Palette
- when some file is opened - all custom commands are shown in Commands Palette.

So no commands are unloaded from Command Palette.
I still want my custom command to be visible always in Commands Palette.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that for command to be visible always it should be a successor of `sublime_plugin.WindowCommand` :) In my case it was derived from `sublime_plugin.TextCommand` that is why it was not visible while no file was opened.

Comment: this information should be edited into your question, as it is not an answer - it is simply a few more details you left out of your original research.

Comment: I hope it is better like it is now )